# Duct resistance: Is one bottleneck the same as long narrow piping?

Tags: pressure, flow

I know that a pressure loss in a ducting (e.g. for a kitchen hood) depends on the air flow, ducting length, diameter (and surface properties, temperature, humidity etc., but let's ignore that for now). I'm fine with that, but what puzzles me is the following:

I have found [an article](https://digestoresirius.cz/jake-odtahove-potrubi/) (in Czech unfortunately) that claims: *If a 150mm diameter ducting is narrowed to 120mm for only 0.2 metres, its properties* are the same as if it were all 120mm.*

* (by "properties" I guess they mean air flow and noise, based on the article, and these two things are also what I care about.)

So basically they claim that the only thing that matters is the narrowest point diameter. This seems counter-intuitive to me, and e.g. an analogy with wiring doesn't work that way -- a short segment of thinner wire won't influence the loss over the thicker part this way.

So I wonder:

1. Is the claim true?
2. If it is true, what is the reason? Why exactly air behaves this way and why the analogy with wires fails?

Answer (score 2):

They need to be very specific on what they mean by "properties." If they mean the total flow capacity at a given upstream pressure, their statement may well be true. If it were all 120 mm, there would still be a reduction at the duct entrance from "very wide" to 120 mm.  A reduction from 150 to 120 mm may be essentially the same as that from a flow conductance standpoint, and for an air ventilation system at low pressure (about 1 atm), the reduction pressure loss probably vastly outweighs the "major" losses from the straight runs of 120 or 150 mm ducting.

This is not true for all cases at all times. For example, in a water pipeline of the same dimensions, long runs of 120 mm can cause major pressure losses significantly greater than the losses from a size reduction.

Comment: Thanks! I'll clarify how I read "properties" based on what the article discusses, but it's mostly concerning air flow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and there are rules of thumb used by ducting designers all over the world to take this into account.

For example a single sharp right-angle bend in an air duct will introduce the same amount of frictional resistance to flow as a straight length of that duct in which the duct length is roughly equal to ten duct diameters. This is a big deal in duct design!

So your intuition about wires and electricity is wrong too. Here's why: note that the skinnier piece of wire will have a slightly greater amount of electrical resistance per foot than the fatter wire connected to it, and since they are in *series*, the skinnier piece of wire will choke the flow of electricity through the *whole circuit*.